# background-image disappearing in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

In a website I am developing, the background image is disappearing in Chrome. It is working fine in Edge and Firefox. I tried it in Another laptop to assure the problem is with Chrome and same in other laptop too. On inspecting, I found that for some unknown reason, Chrome automatically adds a property `background-image: none;` directly to the element.
[See the faulty code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoIKe.png)

This overwrites the property and div and makes background none. On disabling this property in inspect tool, the background images appears but refreshing page brings back the problem.

Comment: isn't the website deployed so we can check it online?

Comment: As suggested in an answer, Ad Blockers or similar extensions might automatically stop certain images from loading if they match certain criteria. For instance, typical ad image dimensions (e.g. `300x250`, `720x90`, etc) or a particular naming convention (e.g. `banner_`, `leaderboard_`, etc) might automatically be blocked if an extension has those rules.

Comment: Is your question "How can I get my background image to display in Chrome?"

Comment: @amirify I am still developing it. But I have a similar kind of problem with iframe tags. 
Chrome automatically adds "left: -10000px !important;position: absolute !important;" directly to element and so it disappears. On removing the "left: -10000px;" from inspect tool in chrome, the iframe element appears. You can see the problem in tinytmce editor at https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/demo/basic-example/. The id of the iframe is "basic-example_ifr". The area of typing disappears. Tested in Ubuntu, Windows and Manjaro.

Comment: @Jujucat No.. The background image is present and visible in other browsers

Comment: @BumhanYu Thank you for your suggestion. But it seems that removing Ad-Blocker does not help. Please check my previous comment for another instance of similar problem but with iframe

Comment: @amirify I have found another instance of background image disappearing.. Please check http://futurepointedu.co.in/.. The div having id="home" has the background image. The background image is added using CSS on class "banner"

Comment: @SuryansGoel `futurepointedu.co.in` page background displays fine for me, and I can't tell what I'm looking for on `tiny.cloud` page. Could you bring the actual code example that you're dealing with? Typically, "real problem" helps figure out "real solutions"

Comment: Yes, @SuryansGoel, I know that. The question is not clear, however. What does the OP want from us?

Answer (score 1):

Well, here i have suggestions for you:

1. Check if any adblocker is working in your chrome or not. If yes, then please remove it, and try again.
2. Do not run the code at Chrome's incognito
3. Add the style elements at the head section of your HTML file.

Please let me know if it works or not. Don't hesitate to ask further questions.

Comment: Thank you  for the suggestion but it seems that removing the Ad-Blocker does not help. I have a similar kind of problem with iframe tags. Chrome automatically adds "left: -10000px !important;position: absolute !important;" directly to element and so it disappears. On removing the "left: -10000px;" from inspect tool in chrome, the iframe element appears. You can see the problem in tinytmce editor at https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/demo/basic-example/. The id of the iframe is "basic-example_ifr". The area of typing disappears. Tested in Ubuntu, Windows and Manjaro.

Comment: You're describing certain sets of CSS rules being applied to certain elements. That sounds very much like an extension's behavior rather than the browser itself. Did you try in incognito mode with all the extensions disabled?

Comment: @BumhanYu Thanks a lot. I found out the real problem. It was an extension but not the Ad-Blocker.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the root cause. It was due to an extension. It was not the Ad-Blocker in my case. Removing that extension has solved my problem